Fingerprint not showing/working in Ubuntu 24.04 | HP
How to get fingerprint working in ubuntu 24.04 | HP Elitebook?
fingerprint is not available in settings.
aarib@aarib-Mi-NoteBook-14:~$ sudo dmidecode | grep -A 9 "System Information"
System Information
    Manufacturer: HP
    Product Name: HP EliteBook x360 1040 G8 Notebook PC
    Family: 103C_5336AN HP EliteBook x360

aarib@aarib-Mi-NoteBook-14:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 04f2:b6c6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 06cb:00e9 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 8087:0026 Intel Corp. AX201 Bluetooth
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub


aarib@aarib-Mi-NoteBook-14:~$ fprintd-enroll
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available


The post lacks of a question. Please edit your post and add the question(s).
